# como quitar el espacio entre los componentes vue (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Estoy tratando de crear una pequenia parte donde mostrara el subtotal, iva y total de los productos que se agregen al datatable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me gustaria tener los componentes mas unidos para que tengo un poco mas de vista

```css
.Total {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  background: red;
}

.valTotal {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<v-card-actions>
  <v-row>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="4" md="6">
      <v-text-field class="valTotal" label="SubTotal" :readonly="true" outlined v-model="csubtotal" dense></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="4" md="6">
      <v-text-field class="valTotal" label="IVA" :readonly="true" outlined v-model="civa" dense></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-text-field class="Total" label="IVA" :readonly="true" outlined v-model="civa" dense></v-text-field>
  </v-row>
</v-card-actions>
```

El primer codigo es el css pero no logro quitar el espacio

la parte de abajo es la parte de HTML-vue

Answer (score 0):

Puedes escribir `.Total input` para apuntar el `input`.

Por ejemplo:

```
.Total input {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```